# Map return multi components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

i'm trying to maping two component but i get this error :

Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (72:7)

```
import AlertListItem from '~/components/Dashboard/AlertListItem'
import AlertItem from '~/components/Dashboard/AlertItem'
    let items
    if (result) {
      items = result.map((item, index) =>
       return(
        <div>
        <AlertListItem key={item.id} item={item} onPopup={this._onSelect} index={index} />
        <AlertItem id={item.id} item={item} onClose={this._onDeselect} />
        </div>  
      )
    )
```

any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a *concise* arrow function (no `{}`), you don't use the `return` keyword; the body of the concise arrow function is a single *expression*, but `return` is a statement. (You also have a `)` instead of `}` closing the `if` block.)

So:

```
import AlertListItem from '~/components/Dashboard/AlertListItem'
import AlertItem from '~/components/Dashboard/AlertItem'

    let items
    if (result) {
      items = result.map((item, index) =>
        <div>
        <AlertListItem key={item.id} item={item} onPopup={this._onSelect} index={index} />
        <AlertItem id={item.id} item={item} onClose={this._onDeselect} />
        </div>  
      )
    }
```

Example *(this also has the change called out in the "Side Note" below)*:

```js
// Setup:
const AlertListItem = props =>
  <div>{props.children}</div>;

const AlertItem = props =>
  <div>Item #{props.id}</div>;

const result = [
  {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}
];

// Your corrected code (with the event handlers removed,
// don't need them for the example)
let items;
if (result) {
  items = result.map((item, index) =>
    <div key={item.id}>
    <AlertListItem item={item} index={index} />
    <AlertItem id={item.id} item={item} />
    </div>  
  )
}

// Show it
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>{items}</div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Just for completeness, here's a simpler example of a *concise* arrow function:

```
array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

Note how the body is just the expression `a - b`.

And the equivalent verbose one:

```
array.sort((a, b) => { return a - b; });
```

Since we've used `{...}`, it's a full function body block, which contains statements, so we use `return` to return a value.

---

Side note: You need to put the `key` on the `div`, not the `AlertListItem`; if you use the non-minified library, it'll warn you about getting `key` wrong. I've moved `key` in my example above.

Comment: the same error when i put if statement         <div>
       `<AlertListItem key={item.id} item={item} onPopup={this._onSelect} index={index} />`
        `if (selection >= 0) {` 
        `<AlertItem key={item.id} item={item} onClose={this._onDeselect} />`
       ` }`
        `</div>`

Comment: @ragnar: That's not what's in the question, and note that you're trying to use `<AlertItem ... />` as a statement (in an `if` block) in that code.

Comment: i know but i'm trying to use if stament is possible ?

Comment: @ragnar: Then that's a completely separate question to what you've asked and what I and others have answered. Questions on SO are not meant to be moving targets. If you want `AlertListItem` to *maybe* have an `AlertItem` inside it, based on a condition, I suggest researching that and posting a question about it if you don't find an answer. (FWIW, the usual solution is `{selection >= 0 && <AlertItem ... />}`, see [docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly braces for `map`:

```
 items = result.map((item, index) => {...}
```